# How to play my own sound in Scheduled Notifications?

Tags: react-native, notifications, expo, scheduling

I am trying to apply scheduled notification in my app it's working well but without sound so I need help in two things

1) How to play a sound and make with my own mp3 I want to play ?

2) if I have a several times how to modify the code to send local notification every time ?

```
const times = ['1:15 AM', '3:15 PM', '6:00 PM', '8:25 PM', '11:45 PM'];

const localNotification = {
    title : 'Testing',
    body : 'The body ',
    data: { name : 'This is the data'},
    ios : {
      sound : true,
      _displayInForeground  : true
    },
    ChannelAndroid : {
      name  : 'Sound',
      sound : true,
      vibrate : [ 0, 250, 250, 250 ]
    }
  }


 const  schedulingOptions = {
    time : (new Date()).getTime() + 5000,
  }


  const currentTime = `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}`;
  console.log(currentTime);
 const pushTime = '1:52';
 if (currentTime === pushTime) {
  Notifications.scheduleLocalNotificationAsync(localNotification, schedulingOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that using a package called 'react-native-notification-sounds'. Please go through the link and follow the instructions.

https://github.com/saadqbal/react-native-notification-sounds/blob/master/README.md

```js
import NotificationSounds, { playSampleSound } from 'react-native-notification-sounds';
NotificationSounds.getNotifications().then(SoundsList => {
    console.warn('SOUNDS', JSON.stringify(SoundsList));
    playSampleSound(SoundsList[1]); 
});
```